# Print compilation error to stdout in cmake

Tags: java, cmake

I am looking for a way to detect failure during the java compilation, followed by a way to print the error message in stdout instead of redirecting it to a file.

```
function(generate_swagger_code spec_path lang package_name)
  set(target_dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/swagger)
  get_filename_component(fname_noext ${spec_path} NAME_WE)
  add_custom_target(generate_swagger_${fname_noext} ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${target_dir}
    COMMENT "Starting swagger autogeneration in ${target_dir}"
    COMMAND java
      -jar ${SWAGGER_CODEGEN_CLI} generate
      -i ${spec_path}
      -l ${lang}
      -DpackageName=${package_name}
      -o ${target_dir} &> ${target_dir}/autogenerate.log
    VERBATIM
  )
endfunction(generate_swagger_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic linux says that `2>&1` will redirect standard err to standard out. There's no option you can pass to `javac` to do it, so that is your only option.

Detecting the failure is trivial; the return value of the javac command will return a non-zero value; this is basic cmake stuff, any tutorial would cover how to pick that up.

Your question title involves 'compilation error', but your code isn't compiling java code, it's running a VM to do swagger_codegen_cli which is slightly different. It's possible that the SWAGGER_CODEGEN_CLI application doesn't properly register exit codes. There's nothing you can do put a file bug if that is actually the case.